# matlab how to solve sum function

Tags: math, matlab, sum, equation-solving

i have to solve the following formulation in matlab:

[image: formular1]

[image: formular2]

[image: forlular3]

i am looking for the beta value, given is a vector full of wavelet coefficients x =(x_1,..,x_L)! How to solve this function in matlab? Can i use fzero?

edit: at the moment i tried this:

```
syms beta
x = [-1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
exp1 = sum((abs(x).^beta).* log(x)) /sum(abs(x).^beta)
exp2 = log(beta/size(x)*sum(abs(x).^beta))/beta
exp3 = (exp(-t)*t^((1/beta)-1))/int(exp(-t)*t^((1/beta)-1),0,inf)
fzero(exp1-exp2-exp3-1,1)
```

but still errors..

Comment: well i started with something like this: syms beta
x = [-1; 2; 3; 4; 5];
sum1 = symsum(abs(x)^beta * log(abs(x))) but its not working.. i need some hints!

Comment: Well, without a good initial value or bracketing interval for β, you're sunk.

Answer (score 1):

`fzero` takes a function handle, rather than a symbolic expression. Try something like this in a .m file

```
function a = myFun(beta)
exp1 = sum((abs(x).^beta).* log(x)) /sum(abs(x).^beta)
exp2 = log(beta/size(x)*sum(abs(x).^beta))/beta
exp3 = (exp(-t)*t^((1/beta)-1))/int(exp(-t)*t^((1/beta)-1),0,inf)
a = exp1-exp2-exp3-1
```

And then,

```
fzero(@myFun,1)
```

I don't know whether this will work. but it is something to try out.